# How do I get Selenium on python to connect to an existing instance of Firefox - I am unable to connect to the marionette port

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, automation

I am trying to use Selenium to connect to existing instance of Firefox - the documentation says to use something like this

```
options=webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'


webdriver_service = Service(r'c:\tmp\geckodriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service = webdriver_service, service_args=['--marionette-port', '2828', '--connect-existing'])
```

However, I get the error

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service = webdriver_service, service_args=['--marionette-port', '2828', '--connect-existing'])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service_args'
```

I see other questions about "unexpected keyword argument", they say latest versions of Selenium has other ways of passing arguments through Options.

I tried

```
options.add_argument('--marionette-port')
options.add_argument('2828') 
options.add_argument('--connect-existing')
```

But it still seems to create a new instance of Firefox

I have started firefox with the following arguments

"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -marionette -start-debugger-server 2828

How do I fix this?

---

These are my versions

Python version

```
python --version
Python 3.12.2
```

Selenium version

```
pip show selenium
Name: selenium
Version: 4.18.1
```

Geckodriver version

```
geckodriver --version
geckodriver 0.34.0 (c44f0d09630a 2024-01-02 15:36 +0000)
```

Firefox 123.0 (64-bit)

Windows 11

Comment: Do not know the answer, but I would try to set lower selenium version first and try on this version. Just to proof your steps are correct in general. Maybe also may help some certain version of FF to be set (older a bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `service_args` parameter in the `Service` class and not on `Firefox`. I believe this should work

```
options=webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'


webdriver_service = Service(r'c:\tmp\geckodriver.exe', service_args=['--marionette-port', '2828', '--connect-existing'])
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service = webdriver_service)
```